# I am having trouble importing modules in pycharm after setting paths for jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pycharm

I am relatively new to python and have been working on pycharm. Recently I began using jupyter notebook and established new PATHS in terminal so I could lunch jupyter from the command line. Ever since then, for some reason I cannot use my already installed modules, such as pandas, numpy or folium on pycharm.

When I run the "import numpy" command I get the following error message, please help!:

"C:\Users\paulov\PycharmProjects\The Basics\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/paulov/PycharmProjects/The Basics/venv/Notes/Getting started with folium.py"
Error processing line 1 of C:\Users\paulov\PycharmProjects\The Basics\venv\lib\site-packages\protobuf-3.13.0-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\paulov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
exec(line)
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 553, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored
Error processing line 1 of C:\Users\paulov\PycharmProjects\The Basics\venv\lib\site-packages\protobuf-3.13.0-nspkg.pth:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\paulov\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site.py", line 169, in addpackage
exec(line)
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 553, in module_from_spec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Remainder of file ignored

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if the python scripts folder are on your Environment Variables.

- Winkey + R, to launch run
- Type control and hit Enter
- Double click System
- Click on Advanced system settings
- Click Environment Variables
- On the system variables, select Path and click Edit.

Check to see if your scripts location is there
C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python<PythonVersion>\Scripts
C:\Users<username>\AppData\Roaming\Python<PythonVersion>\Scripts

Also, from what I know, if you are using virtual environments, you would need to install the packages you need for the specific script/program you are building.